# why the verb of this sentence has a third person "s"? It must be "increase"

Tags: grammar, third-person-singular

"As people live longer into their old age, the chances of them suffering from serious illnesses increases." I came across this sentence in Mindset 3 as a sample for writing. Is it correct? "increases"

Comment: You are right. Since chances are plural, the verb should be in plural form (increase).

Answer (score 1):

As **Chances** is plural, the verb should definitely be **Increase**.

What you're seeing is probably a typing mistake, if not a clear grammatical one.

Comment: something is confusing, look at this sentences from coca. "the chances of them relapsing and doing something harmful or getting worse is higher." "the chances of them getting good vegetarian food without having to sell their kidney is most definitely.."

Comment: Those are both errors as explained above.

Comment: @mostafakarami This example is wrong too. **are** should have been used.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there is no mistake in coca but your response is clear.